# extract frame from video from xuggler

Tags: java, xuggler

I want Images from video using xuggler 5.4 but help of IOStream in java.I did but my code is stuck in container.open() method my IDE(Net Beans 7.2) show like code running but after waiting long time same thing it show.
Plz verify my code and correct me.

```
public class DecodeAndCaptureFrames
{
  public static final double SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES = 5;
  public static final long NANO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES = 
    (long)(Global.DEFAULT_PTS_PER_SECOND * SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES);

  private static long mLastPtsWrite = Global.NO_PTS;

  private static void processFrame(IVideoPicture picture, BufferedImage image)
  {
    try
    {

      if (mLastPtsWrite == Global.NO_PTS)
        mLastPtsWrite = picture.getPts() - NANO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES;
      if (picture.getPts() - mLastPtsWrite >= NANO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES)
      {

        File file = File.createTempFile("frame", ".png");

        ImageIO.write(image, "png", file);
        double seconds = ((double)picture.getPts()) / Global.DEFAULT_PTS_PER_SECOND;
        System.out.printf("at elapsed time of %6.3f seconds wrote: %s\n",
          seconds, file);        
        mLastPtsWrite += NANO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES;
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
      File f = new File("/root/Downloads/15465.mp4");
       InputStream input = new FileInputStream(f);
        System.out.println(input);
    if (!IVideoResampler.isSupported(
        IVideoResampler.Feature.FEATURE_COLORSPACECONVERSION))
      throw new RuntimeException(
        "you must install the GPL version of Xuggler (with IVideoResampler" + 
        " support) for this demo to work");
    IContainer container = IContainer.make();
    if (container.open(input, null) < 0)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("could not open file: ");
    int numStreams = container.getNumStreams();    
      System.out.println(numStreams);

    int videoStreamId = -1;
    IStreamCoder videoCoder = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < numStreams; i++)
    {
      IStream stream = container.getStream(i);

      IStreamCoder coder = stream.getStreamCoder();

      if (coder.getCodecType() == ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO)
      {
        videoStreamId = i;
        videoCoder = coder;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (videoStreamId == -1)
      throw new RuntimeException("could not find video stream in container: ");

    if (videoCoder.open() < 0)
      throw new RuntimeException(
        "could not open video decoder for container: " );

    IVideoResampler resampler = null;
    if (videoCoder.getPixelType() != IPixelFormat.Type.BGR24)
    {
      resampler = IVideoResampler.make(
        videoCoder.getWidth(), videoCoder.getHeight(), IPixelFormat.Type.BGR24,
        videoCoder.getWidth(), videoCoder.getHeight(), videoCoder.getPixelType());
      if (resampler == null)
        throw new RuntimeException(
          "could not create color space resampler for: " );
    }


    IPacket packet = IPacket.make();
    while(container.readNextPacket(packet) >= 0)
    {

      if (packet.getStreamIndex() == videoStreamId)
      {
        IVideoPicture picture = IVideoPicture.make(videoCoder.getPixelType(),
            videoCoder.getWidth(), videoCoder.getHeight());

        int offset = 0;
        while(offset < packet.getSize())
        {
        int bytesDecoded = videoCoder.decodeVideo(picture, packet, offset);
          if (bytesDecoded < 0)
            throw new RuntimeException("got error decoding video in: " );
          offset += bytesDecoded;

          if (picture.isComplete())
          {
            IVideoPicture newPic = picture;

            if (resampler != null)
            {
              // we must resample
              newPic = IVideoPicture.make(
                resampler.getOutputPixelFormat(), picture.getWidth(), 
                picture.getHeight());
              if (resampler.resample(newPic, picture) < 0)
                throw new RuntimeException(
                  "could not resample video from: " );
            }

            if (newPic.getPixelType() != IPixelFormat.Type.BGR24)
              throw new RuntimeException(
                "could not decode video as BGR 24 bit data in: " );
            BufferedImage javaImage = Utils.videoPictureToImage(newPic);
            processFrame(newPic, javaImage);
          }
        }
      }
      else
      {
        // This packet isn't part of our video stream, so we just
        // silently drop it.
        do {} while(false);
      }
    }

    if (videoCoder != null)
    {
      videoCoder.close();
      videoCoder = null;
    }
    if (container !=null)
    {
      container.close();
      container = null;
    }
  }
}
```